# Xcode 4 - IB - evenly distribute controls?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

In Interface Builder I have a bunch of text fields that sit vertically. I want them evenly distributed in the vertical space, and all to be identically sized.

I've found the Alignment menu that lets you line up items. I can't find a menu for distribution or sizing. Does Xcode 4 include those layout commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boring answer is to type in the coordinates manually. Not very smooth, but it gives you exact control over the placement at least (in the Size inspector).

Answer (score 28):

The answer is, **NO**.  And I **HATE** having to be "one of those people" that has to tell you so.  I *assume* what you are looking for is something similar to OmniGraffle's quintessential feature, "Canvas, Grid, Alignment".  It is THE TOOL that makes OG so damned good.

[image: alignment, dumbies]

It amazes / disgusts me that a company worth $100 billion is unable to get this basic tenet of visual layout right, when a company writing software for that same idiotic company's own platform for years, has had this down for as long as I can remember.  The Xcode team **needs to pull it together**.  For example, KVO Bindings are, and have always been a joke - a not so funny one - that are impossible to implement, plug-ins are gone…  And IMHO, Lion auto-layout is Unusable.  They need some NEW PEOPLE or something, maybe that *aren't developers, or something*..  Cause Xcode is getting harder to use, not easier.  It looks better, and is better organized… but its obvious that there is no "big thinker" inside that group that is willing to question their fragile and awkward paradigms.

[image: the jokes on us, lion autolayout]

Are they kidding with this?  How about this Xcode? _Shut up, line up the buttons, distribute then evenly - like 99% of people are going to want, 99% of the time - and dont puke meaningless lines all over everything?__ And *what the hell* is `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority`?  I read the docs twice and still have NO IDEA what those are or how to use them.  I'm no Einstein, but If I can't "get it" after making a concerted effort… It's too hard.  lol.   Ok, I need to go mark futile rant off my to-do list, now.

Comment: Maybe they know what `Content Hugging Priority` is.

Comment: Really can't agree emphatically enough with this. They have a great foundation in Obj-C/Cocoa but their development tools and their recent APIs seem to have been designed by people that haven't had to actually use them to build real apps. IB is next to unusable for complex layouts and extremely basic features like zooming and distributing controls are just completely missing.

Comment: To clarify what those are: under Auto Layout, there's a bunch of objects called *constraints*. Constraints want to push or pull UI elements in certain directions; how badly they want to do so is measured by the constraint's *priority*. Content Hugging/Compression Resistance Priority is how badly a particular element wants to (a) be *as small as it can* to fit its content and (b) be *no smaller*, respectively. The interaction of constraints' priorities and these priorities ultimately determines where your UI elements go at runtime.

Comment: Agreed and it still hasn't improved with Xcode 5.  I am ready to smash my MacBook to bits after spending hours trying to get a window controller to align its views and make it all resizable.  Ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

The concept is to use some spacer views and set them to be all the same size. There are some tricks with the priorities to be done so please follow the link for a definite answer.